# Classic ASP: Get "Authorization" Header

Tags: authentication, asp-classic, http-headers

I've been searching for a solution on the internet for this, and can not find it anywhere.

I've setup a simple POST request through Fiddler for an ASP page on my local machine:

```
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Host: localhost
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: Basic xW91bsdtcyNqYTpfs8Jkb4ql
Content-Length: 9

asdfdfdsf
```

The ASP page contains the following line:

```
Response.Write(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_Authorization"))
```

Instead of writing out "Basic .....", it doesn't write anything at all.  If I change "HTTP_Authorization" to any of the other headers (HTTP_Content_Length), I can pull in their values.

Is there a reason ASP is refusing to let me see that specific header?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was being removed by the server's windows auth

I unchecked "Integrated Windows authentication" and the header started showing up correctly